# Downgrade PHP from 5.5.9 to 5.2.4

Tags: 14.04, php, downgrade

I want to downgrade PHP for testing purpose. How i can safely do it?
I have

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

Answer (score 0):

you can install both php versions parallel e.g. PHP 5.5x and 5.3x or even three PHP versions parallel e.g. PHP 5.5x , 5.4x and 5.3x using fastcgi.

Just follow these instructions:

http://www.jabommi.de/wiki/downgrade-php-5-5-to-5-3-ubuntu-14-with-multiple-php-versions/

The tutorial is based on Ubuntu 14.